# Two different Eclipse instances working in same path

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, tdd, workspace, truestudio

Due to plugin compatibility problems between the Eclipse applications Atollic TrueStudio 9.0 and Cantata 7.2 (Testframework) i have to use both eclipse versions at the same time as single instances instead of having one Eclipse with plugins of TrueStudio and Cantata.

I want to use them for TDD in my current embedded C project. Git-Repo looks like that:

"Project"
  
 -->src
  
 -->tests

TrueStudio just need the src folder but Cantata ("tests" folder) needs src and tests folder to create testscripts,...

Same workspace with two eclipse instances is not possible. Two workspaces and changing the default location to the Git-Clone path in every eclipse instance also cause troubles.

Does someone know a practical solution for this problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a second workspace for one of the instances and create a project in it with linked resources pointing to the first workspace (see https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm)

Comment: Yeah, i tried it with the linked resources. Actually i created seperate workspaces in "src" and "tests". I made a link from "src" into "tests" and it seems to work pretty good. Only thing thats annoying is that i have to do the import again if a new source file in "src" was created.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but you could try to enable "General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks or polling" in the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: Ah okay, now the refreshment of the linked source files is done without request. Thats a pretty cool, thanks ;)
But i am still not able to get new source files from a linked directory. But i think thats because if you are importing a folder from a existing file system you have to check the files you want to link... if you create files afterwards inside the linked folder you have to do the import again :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you did - you should be able to link the folders, not individual files.

Comment: Ahhh sorry... my fault. 
I used the "Import", not the linked resources function... Now it works like expected. Thanks a lot ;)